# Error can not load such file -- libxml_ruby (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, xml-libxml

i am a newbine in ruby. I just install success module libxml-ruby. When i run a script which has require 'xml', it apprears error:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- libxml_ruby (LoadError)
```

My script very simple such as:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
require 'xml'
# proccess with xml file
va1=1
va2=2
puts va1+va2
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is `libxml-ruby`, just run `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`. this solved my question.

Answer (score -1):

I have meet this problem.It seems that ruby lacks some packages. You can use

```
gem install bundler;
gem install libxml;
```

to have a try.